# Proceso de carga masiva de datos en postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

He estado investigando al respecto y sinceramente lo que encuentro de información no me convence (poca información, por cierto) lo que trato de hacer es ingresar 5000 datos en 4 tablas distintas de postgresql y he encontrado que la función COPY funciona para un archivo csv, pero no entiendo algo:
¿Tengo que escribir los 5000 datos en el excel? 
porque lo que busco es que me los genere automáticamente, sé que en MySql existe cierta forma de hacerlo, pero en postgresql cómo es ese proceso? o no existe algo similar? 
He investigado pero no logro comprenderlo todo, también traté con el manual de postgresql pero no encontré dicha información.

También he escuchado que desde PHP o Java puede hacerse esto, cuál sería ese proceso?

Comment: ¿Esos 5000 datos los tienes o pueden ser datos ficticios?

Comment: @Gonzo30 has investigado algo de bulkinsert puede ser hasta un archivo texto con los insert

Comment: @Kiko_L pueden ser ficticios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es generar 5000 filas aleatorias para importarlas en tus tablas te recomiendo https://mockaroo.com/.

No tienes más que definir los campos de la tabla, el número de filas y te los genera en el formato que quieras (CSV, JSON, SQL, etc.)